# Pandas Custom Business Day Calendar Offset

Tags: python, datetime, datetimeoffset

'This is a basic question that I can't seem to find addressed anywhere.

I understand how to make a custom business day calendar per the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

However, I have a datetime index that is already created and is 'customized'.  It is a date range with particular dates eliminated:

```
custom_datelist:

2003-01-02
2003-01-03
2003-01-05
2003-01-06
2003-01-09
...
```

So, with this calendar, how do I create a date offset?  The documentation indicates how to generate the date series but it isn't clear about the offset in this case.  Would my offset simply be:

```
pd.to_datetime('2003-01-06') + 1*custom_datelist
```

give me `pd.to_datetime('2003-01-09')`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to infer/create the pandas DateOffset from an existing datetime index?