# Python Pandas add date offset column with custom business day (CDay; CustomBusinessDay)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to add a custom business day offset column to a date column:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ship_date_et': ['2018-10-01' for x in range(10)], 'offset': [x for x in range(10)]})

>> df['offset'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['offset'], unit='D')

>> df['ship_date_et'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ship_date_et'])

>> df.dtypes
offset          timedelta64[ns]
ship_date_et     datetime64[ns]

>> df
    offset ship_date_et
0   0 days  2018-10-01
1   1 days  2018-10-01
2   2 days  2018-10-01
3   3 days  2018-10-01
4   4 days  2018-10-01
5   5 days  2018-10-01
6   6 days  2018-10-01
7   7 days  2018-10-01
8   8 days  2018-10-01
9   9 days  2018-10-01

>> holidays = ['2018-10-10'] # '2018-10-10' just a made-up holiday

>> cdays = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays, weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri') 

>> df['ship_date_et'] + df['offset'].apply(cdays)
0   2018-10-02
1   2018-10-03
2   2018-10-04
3   2018-10-05
4   2018-10-06
5   2018-10-07
6   2018-10-08
7   2018-10-09
8   2018-10-10
9   2018-10-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Which is crazy wrong. The weekend (2018-10-06 and 2018-10-07) isn't calculated (which Pandas docs says that `CDay` incorporates Weekends). Which is beside the point that I've only defined 2 `weekmask` days (Mon & Tue).

I'm truly confused and frustrated because this works with normal `BDay`:

```
>> df['ship_date_et'] + df['offset'].dt.days.apply(BDay) # Doing dt.days to get integer for BDay since we defined df['offset'] as a `timedelta`
0   2018-10-01
1   2018-10-02
2   2018-10-03
3   2018-10-04
4   2018-10-05
5   2018-10-08
6   2018-10-09
7   2018-10-10
8   2018-10-11
9   2018-10-12
```

My desired result:

```
>> df['ship_date_et'] + df['offset'].apply(cdays)
0   2018-10-01
1   2018-10-02
2   2018-10-03
3   2018-10-04
4   2018-10-05
5   2018-10-08
6   2018-10-09
7   2018-10-11
8   2018-10-12
9   2018-10-15
```

I've read through the docs (both numpy `busday` and Pandas) and scoured the internet e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834946/pandas-offset-datetimeindex-to-next-business-if-date-is-not-a-business-day) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737245/pandas-custom-business-day-calendar-offset)), but cannot find a reason for what's happening. The most concerning part is that my `cdays` definition, at `index=0` is `0 days`, but the result returns my `ship_date_et` days + 1.

Of course, there is an issue too about using `apply` and the:

```
PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to Series not vectorized "Series not vectorized"
```

Pandas gives.

I would appreciate any feedback or input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only applying cdays to the offset and not the ship_date+offset.

```
(df['ship_date_et'] + df['offset']).apply(cdays)
```

Answer (score 0):

@dlstadther, while your answer did give me date offsets, it was not seeing the weekends or holidays as zeros. I think this has to do with my implementation of `df['offset']` as `type timedelta`. This resulted in:

```
>> (df['ship_date_et'] + df['offset']).apply(cdays)
0   2018-10-02
1   2018-10-03
2   2018-10-04
3   2018-10-05
4   2018-10-08
5   2018-10-08
6   2018-10-08
7   2018-10-09
8   2018-10-11
9   2018-10-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

which wasn't seeing the weekends and holidays as zeros, non-existent, whatever you want to think, and continuing the counter after them. I'd say that was due to my inability to ask a good question.

## My Answer:

With a little bit of sleep and finagling:

```
>> df['new'] = df['ship_date_et'] + df['offset'].dt.days*cdays
```

is what I was looking for.

```
>> df
offset ship_date_et        new
0 0 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-01
1 1 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-02
2 2 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-03
3 3 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-04
4 4 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-05
5 5 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-08
6 6 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-09
7 7 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-11
8 8 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-12
9 9 days   2018-10-01 2018-10-15
```

where "holidays" and weekends in this example are skipped over, and the counter continues past them just like `BDay`.

If `df['offset']` is of type `int`, will not have to do `.dt.days`.